# How to choose JDK 10 or 11 in Intellij IDE?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I'm on `Intellij 2018.2.1`, Ubuntu `18.04.1` and having trouble to chose the `JDK` in IDE settings. None of the following can be selected:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Result:

> The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK.

`java -version` shows `openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17`.

What can I do?

Comment: IIRC, `which java` will show you the path to which JDK is being used (so you can double-check your paths).

Comment: it shows `/usr/bin/java`, but anyways it should be possible to just select the desired jdk inside intellij, shouldn't it?

Comment: @membersound what IDE version do you use? Please provide the tree listing of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just run another `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk`, which magically solved the problem...